# How to type the 'ro' kana and yen symbol directly with US keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I recently brought the Japanese 106/109 keyboard stickers for my US keyboard. I applied stickers and changed my hardware keyboard layout from English 101/102 to Japanese 106/109. Then I realized that I can't type the Japanese 'ro' and yen symbol directly. After a bit of research, I found [this guide](https://www.instructables.com/US-to-Japanese-Keyboard-Conversion-Missing-RO-Key/). Unfortunately, this guide doesn't work because I don't own the Japanese keyboard. I tried [powertoys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) to remap a certain key to type the 'ro' kana but I have no idea what is the virtual key number for this kana. I looked up [this documentation](http://kbdlayout.info/kbd106n) and it doesn't help because it didn't include the 'ro' kana and yen symbol. Any ideas on how to configure my keyboard so I can type the 'ro' kana and yen symbol directly?

I use Windows 10 and Google IME to type Japanese.

Comment: IIRC, the Japanese keyboard has an extra key just to left of Enter key for the ¥ (alt+0165) key. Since this key isn't there on other keyboards, you're probably stuck. I don't recall where the ろ key is on a Japanese keyboard though. If you're using Office, you might be able to create an AutoCorrect setting to convert e.g. "YEN" to the yen symbol.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg so it is not possible to use software to map keys on my keyboard to type the yen symbol and the ro kana?

Comment: This thread mentions a Registry tweak to make it happen. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/microsoft-ime-japanese-keyboard-layout-windows-10/769eae96-2451-4b69-a1cb-b251b5285b15 Worth a try.

Comment: @JimmyYang I'm guessing you could do this with software that remaps the keyboard (assuming you're willing to give up some other key to get the ro/yen keys).  I googled "windows remap keys" (w/o quotes) and got several leads. MS has a program for their own keyboards, but more generally there's this:  https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-remap-your-keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my keyboard issue. This answer serves as a future reference. I used [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) to map my left and right Windows keys to type ろ and 円 directly. I found scancodes for these characters from [this website](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-8.html). SharpKeys surprisingly supports many scancodes, far more than PowerToys and KeyTweak. I highly recommend SharpKeys to anyone who faces a similar issue in future.